# Check if Google Play Service is up to date

Tags: google-account, google, sony-xperia, sony-xperia-z

I have a Sony Xperia Z3 compact, and when I trying to broadcast my video live on YouTube from Xperia , I sign in with Google+ account and I received "Error when trying to sign in, please check if Google Play Service is up to date",what to do? ... When I buy my phone I updated all applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a workaround you could sideload the last Google Play Services app.

You can check your version under Settings > Apps > All tab > Google Play Services.

[Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en) in the Google Play Store you will find the latest version number or alternatively [here at Google](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html) with some more in-depth info.

As a resource you could try and trust (hopefully) [androidpolice.com](http://www.androidpolice.com/?s=google%20play%20services) and search for Google Play Services, download the app, allow *Unknown sources* under settings and sideload (install) the app.
/Update: APKMirror is the 'new' service from androidpolice where you find all apk's. [Search here](https://www.apkmirror.com/?s=Play%20Services&post_type=apps_post).

But usually after a short time Play Services should update automatically.

Answer (score 5):

Check installed version **via terminal**:

```
adb shell 
pm dump com.google.android.gms|grep version
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install [ApkTrack](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=fr.kwiatkowski.ApkTrack) from [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/) which checks periodically for updates to the installed applications. It uses multiple sources for checking if the applications have an update.

Just install it, open and tap on refresh button.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Google Play.
2. Tap the profile picture at the top right corner.
3. Settings.
4. About.
5. Play Store Version.